# After insert in one table, insert into another table in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

What I would like to do is; 
after I insert some data into table1, I would like some of that data automatically inserted into table2, such as the primary key from table1 inserted into table2 as a foreign key.

Is this done using a trigger.
Not sure where to start looking first.

Cheers
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that through trigger. You can do it like this:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger 
  before INSERT ON table1 
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW 
  for each row
  BEGIN
    insert into table2(fk_column,column1) values(:new.pk_column_of_table1,'value1');
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a trigger as @vance said and you can use returning into clause if you are populating some of the columns dynamically

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (t1_seq.nextval, 'FOUR')
  RETURNING id INTO l_id;
```

have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm)